# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' in typrscript

Tags: typescript

I am new to type script. I am writing a function to format a string.

```
type patamTypes = string | number | number[];

function myFunc(sTemplate: string, params: patamTypes): string {
   
     if (typeof params == 'string'){
         params = [params]; //getting the error here
     }

}
```

I am getting this error. `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: `paramTypes` only allows a string, a number, or array of numbers to be assigned. You're trying to assign an array of strings. What do you actually want/need to do here? Either your type is wrong or the logic of your code is wrong, I don't know which one needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `patamTypes` can be either a string or a number or an array of numbers. After type checking that `params` is a string you're trying to mutate it to the array of strings which is incompatible with what you have defined in `patamType` - the only array acceptable for your type is an array of numbers.

If you wish to convert the string to a number then do it before mutating the `params` to an array.